# Leaflet, L.WFST : show a Popup for the attribute

Tags: leaflet, wfs

could you please help me on this ?
It's not showing the Attribute in Bindpopup
of a map in Leaflet
with this Javascript: https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet-wfst.src.js

```
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) { 
     if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) { 
       layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name + '</br>' + feature.properties.name) ;
   } 
};

var wfstPoly = new L.WFST({
    url: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/ows',
    typeNS: 'worldmap',
    typeName: 'tracks.raam.steps',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    geometryField: 'geom',
    forceMulti: true,
    schema: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=opendata:sites',
    style: {
      color: 'blue',
      weight: 2
    },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature                   
        } 
    }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Is it imaginable that L.WFST doesn't support Info popups (Bindpopup)? then, is it impossible to display them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L.WFST` layer fires a `click` event. Use that to create a popup. The code should look something like this:

```
var popup = new L.Popup();   

var wfstPoly = new L.WFST({
    url: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/ows',
    typeNS: 'worldmap',
    typeName: 'tracks.raam.steps',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    geometryField: 'geom',
    forceMulti: true,
    schema: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=opendata:sites',
    style: {
      color: 'blue',
      weight: 2
    }
}).addTo(map);

wfstPoly .on('click', function(e){
    if (e.layer.feature.properties && e.layer.feature.properties.name) { 
       popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
           .setContent(e.layer.feature.properties.name + '</br>' + e.layer.feature.properties.name)
           .openOn(map);
     }
})
```

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST/blob/master/examples/popup.html) example.

Note: changed a bit

Comment: thank you for helping! It works. I'll just be removing some quotes in setcontent in your example for it to work